# LINQ One to Many, 3 levels Deep Question

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, one-to-many

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong in the below LINQ statement.  It doesn't like the third `SELECT`.  It finds `tblAddresse.tblAdminCounty` in Intelisense when I am typing the query but when I type the SELECT after it it freaks.

Does it have to do with how `tblAddress` and `tblAdminCounty` are related?  I would have thought that the fact it shows in Intellisense under `tblAddress` would make that statement self-evident but obviously not.

If I was to query just the CountyName in a seperate function it would look like this -->

```
var countyName = from adminCounty in context.tblAdminCounties
                 where adminCounty.CountyID == countyID
                 select adminCounty.CountyName;
```

And this is the larger 3-tiered approach based on this site --> [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/02/20/one-to-many-and-joins.aspx)

```
var query = from tblBusinesse in context.tblBusinesses
            where tblBusinesse.BusinessID == businessID
            select new
            {
                tblBusinesse.BusinessName,
                tblBusinesse.ContactName,
                tblBusinesse.EmailAddress,
                Address = from tblAddresse in tblBusinesse.tblAddresses 
                      select new 
                      { 
                          tblAddresse.AddressLine1, 
                          tblAddresse.AddressLine2, 
                          tblAddresse.AddressLine3, 
                          tblAddresse.CityName, 
                          County = from adminCounty in tblAddresse.tblAdminCounty
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       adminCounty.CountyName
                                   }

                      }
            };
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you, I can never seem to get my code to format correctly.  I guess that alone should explain a lot...

Comment: I suspect you'd also find life easier if you didn't have "tbl" in front of everything :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: :) Indeed!  Luckily, in this case, that is only in the sample code I posted and not in my actual code base for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to query it as if a single address has multiple counties. Doesn't the fact that it's called `tblAdminCounty` rather than `tblAdminCounties` suggest that it's just a single item?

Try changing this:

```
County = from adminCounty in tblAddresse.tblAdminCounty
         select new
         {
             adminCounty.CountyName
         }
```

to just:

```
County = tblAddresse.tblAdminCounty
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I guess I wasn't fully understanding what the sub-query meant.